# Sort a list of numbers with all 0's at the end of result

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the list of persons and if the list of Input is `3,0,2,7,0,8`

I want the output to be `2,3,7,8,0,0`

With the following code, i can sort only non zero numbers to get `2,3,7,8` as output.

```
sortedList = personList.stream()
                       .filter(Person -> Person.getAge()>0)
                       .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());

zeroList=personList.stream()
                       .filter(Person -> Person.getAge()==0)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());

sortedList.addAll(zeroList);
```

Can the above two statements be merged into a single statement?

Comment: Person.getAge()>=0

Answer (score 6):

You can make sure that zeros go to the end by writing an appropriate comparator:

```
sortedList = personList.stream()
   .sorted((p1, p2) -> {
      int a = p1.getAge();
      int b = p2.getAge();
      if (a == 0 && b == 0) return 0;
      if (a == 0) return 1;
      if (b == 0) return -1;
      return Integer.compare(a, b);
   })
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or slightly more compactly:

```
sortedList = personList.stream()
   .sorted((p1, p2) -> {
      int a = p1.getAge();
      int b = p2.getAge();
      return a == 0 || b == 0 ? Integer.compare(b, a) : Integer.compare(a, b);
   })
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I'd tend to write `comparing(p -> p > 0).thenComparingInt(p -> p)`

Answer (score 4):

A nice simple way to put 0s at the end of the sort is to treat them as large values in the comparator:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getAge() == 0 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : p.getAge())
```

An arguably more readable approach is 'sort by inequality to zero and then by value':

```
Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getAge() == 0)
    .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Answer (score 1):

You may concatenate the two stream before building the list:

```
sortedList = Stream<Person>.concat(
   personList.stream().filter(Person -> Person.getAge()>0)
                      .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge)),
   personList.stream().filter(Person -> Person.getAge()==0))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want, is a *rotation*; when you simply sort by age, the elements are in the right order, when you consider the result list to be a ring, so you only want to start the list after the last zero-age value:

```
┌───────────────────────────┐
└─ 0  0  2  3  7  8       <─┘
         2  3  7  8  0  0
```

```
sortedList = personList.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
Collections.rotate(sortedList, -(int)personList.stream().filter(p->p.getAge()==0).count());
```

Alternatively, you can rotate the age values within the `int` value range while comparing. This works, because we can preclude negative ages, so we can rotate the numbers so that zero becomes the `MAX_VALUE` while all other numbers keep their relative order.

```
sortedList = personList.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getAge()-Integer.MIN_VALUE-1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

By the way, this is equivalent to

```
sortedList = personList.stream()
    .sorted((p1, p2) -> Integer.compareUnsigned(p1.getAge()-1, p2.getAge()-1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Understanding the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is needed to understand the solution.

Comment: when I first saw unsigned operations in 8, I thought were in the world would I need that extra one bit. There u go.. :)

Answer (score -2):

You specified a filter `.filter(Person -> Person.getAge()>0)` that does not allow element `equals to 0

You need to change to : `.filter(Person -> Person.getAge()>=0)`

Then you need to specify a more complex comparator

```
sortedlist = personList.stream()
            .filter(Person -> Person.getAge() >= 0)
            .sorted((o1, o2) -> {
                if (o1.getAge() == 0 || o2.getAge() == 0) 
                    return Integer.compare(o2.getAge(), o1.getAge());
                return Integer.compare(o1.getAge(), o2.getAge());
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- If one of the `Person's age` is `0` it'll compare in reverse way (0 will be the bigger numer => at the end)
- if none of ages is `0` : classic comparison between `Integers`

Comment: I want the zeros to be at the end of list